# Concerning pointer to an array of pointers

Tags: c++

I'm currently working on an assignment, and I think I have successfully made a linked list of the elements in a periodic table read from a file (amount of elements will vary).

But I'm now trying to create a pointer to an array of pointers to Element (`Element **ptr = new Element *[n]` is found in main file and is passed into `read_table`). I'm not sure of how I should do this though. Is what I'm doing correct? Or should it be `ptr[i] -> *head.pElement`?

Element struct has been created in another file and table will be a prototype in that file.

```
struct Node {
    Element *pElement;
    Node *next;
};

int table(Element **ptr) { // Was originally Element **&ptr, but that might have been supposed to be for my prototype
    Node *head = new Node; // starts off the linked list
    Node *temp = new Node; // temp node to make switch for head node
    Element e; 

    int counter = 0; // counter to keep track of num of elements

    // open input file
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(file_path_will_be_placed_here);

    // loop to read file and create linked list
    while(infile >> e.atomicNumber) {
        infile >> e.name;
        infile >> e.abbreviation;
        infile >> e.mass;

        head -> pElement = new Element; // the node's pElement points to a new Element
        *head -> pElement = e; // sets node's pElement to the read data stored in e
        *temp -> next = head; // might have to point to &head
        head = temp; // head points to where temp does
        temp = new Node; // temp points to new node

        counter++; // increment counter every time for every element
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
                // confused !@!@?
            ptr[i] -> head.pElement;
    }
```

Comment: "`Element **&ptr`" wheehaaa?? what's that supposed to be? And, no, i don't think your while loop creates a sound linked list. Better seperate this from the function `table()`.

Comment: Umm... wait... A *pointer to pointer to Element reference?*... Very good candidate for a conversion with the duck... See: [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Or a *reference to a pointer to a pointer to Element*? ;) More was asking about its purpose, though.

Comment: @Swordfish Yes. Table is supposed to return the number of elements read from the file and, via a reference parameter, a pointer to an array of pointers to the elements read. The reading in of the table is supposed to be in the table function. Ohh I think that was pose to be in my function prototype, not the function header,

Comment: @Amai Why do you think you need a linked list then? Please step through your code with a [debugger](https://www.amazon.com/Rhode-Island-Novelty-Classic-Rubber/dp/B002SXTPX0?keywords=rubber+duck&qid=1540093573&sr=8-19&ref=sr_1_19).

Comment: @Swordfish I think the & is supposed to be in my function prototype not my header. So it is a reference to a pointer to a pointer to an Element struct. The linked list is to read in the info and keep a counter, so I do not need to read in the info twice.

Comment: @Amai How about `std::vector<Element*>`?

Comment: @Swordfish I haven't learned about that. "This function must read in the data by constructing a linked list and convert the linked list into an array of pointers." was part of instruction for the table portion of my assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> while(infile >> e.atomicNumber) {
>     infile >> e.name;
>     infile >> e.abbreviation;
>     infile >> e.mass;
> ```

First of all, you want all extractions from `infile` to succeed to keep the loop running:

```
while (infile >> e.atomicNumber >> e.name >> e.abbreviation >> infile >> e.mass) {
```

Then let's have a look at your "List":

```
    head->pElement = new Element;  // ok
    *head->pElement = e;           // ok
    *temp->next = head;
    head = temp;                   // now you have a head with a pElement pointing to garbage
                                   // and a next pointing to the node with pElement pointing
                                   // to the Element you just read, the next of that Node
                                   // points to garbage, though *)                                     
    temp = new Node;               

    counter++;
}
```

*) so when you try to go through the list you will have to ignore the `pElement` of head but also won't know when you reached the lists end cause you never set `next`-pointer to `nullptr` so it could be destinguished from a pointer to a next node.

```
int table(Element **&ptr) // should return std::size_t
{
    ifstream infile{ "test.txt" };
    int num_elements{}; // should be std::size_t
    Element e;
    Node *head{};
    Node *current{};
    while (infile >> e.atomicNumber >> e.name >> e.abbreviation >> e.mass) {

        if (!head) {
            head = new Node;
            head->next = nullptr;
            head->pElement = new Element;
            *head->pElement = e;
            current = head;
        }
        else {
            current->next = new Node;
            current = current->next;
            current->next = nullptr;
            current->pElement = new Element;
            *current->pElement = e;
        }
        ++num_elements;
    }

    Element **array = new Element*[num_elements];

    current = head;
    Node *temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_elements && current; ++i) {
        array[i] = current->pElement;
        temp = current;
        current = current->next;
        delete temp;
    }

    ptr = array;
    return num_elements;
}

int main()
{
    Element **elements;
    int num_elements = table(elements);

    // do something with elements

    for(int i{}; i < num_elements; ++i)
        delete elements[i];
    delete [] elements;
}
```

#### The Real<sup>*tm*</sup> Solution:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>

struct Element {
    int atomicNumber;
    std::string name;
    std::string abbreviation;
    double mass;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Element &element)
{
    Element e;
    if (!(is >> e.atomicNumber >> e.name >> e.abbreviation >> e.mass))
        return is;
    element = e;
    return is;
}

std::vector<Element> read_elements()
{
    std::ifstream infile{ "test.txt" };
    std::vector<Element> elements{ std::istream_iterator<Element>{ infile },
                                   std::istream_iterator<Element>{} };
    return elements;
}
```

Comment: The problem is I never learned any of the vector things and the std:: 's.
But on the topic of the initial starter node. Would it be fine if i just set *head -> next = NULL;? I just assumed I wouldn't need to because I would be using the counter to place the elements in an array of pointers to the elements,

Comment: The problem with the not set `pElement` of the head stays the same.

Comment: Ohhh I see what u mean. I put in the *temp -> next = head. So it would always have an empty node. Can I ask what you mean by  "if (!head)", does it mean "if head is not defined"?

Comment: By doing " Node *head{}; " aren't you pretty much setting it as nullptr by default until you define it as something? Sorry bout this, new to C++ so I'm still trying to get used to this.

Comment: Yes, `type foo{}` is *zero-initialization* which is `nullptr` for pointers. "until you define it as something?" that *is* the definition. Everything that follows are assignments.

Comment: So ultimately you are setting the head ptr to nullptr, so wouldn't that make it so "if(!head)", triggers on the second node added then it would alternate between the else/if until you run out of things to add?

Comment: No, it doesn't alternate. `!head` is true the first time the loop body runs. After that `head` never is `nullptr` again.

Comment: Hmm... but isn't "!head" similar to "head != nullptr" (from one of your above comments). And type foo{} initializes head to nullptr (also from a comment), so wouldn't it not trigger the if statements, since "head == nullptr"

Comment: Lets make that easier: `head = 0; if(!head) /* is true for head == 0 */`. `!0` --> `true`, `!anything_other_than_0` --> `false`.

Comment: Oh my god. I'm so sorry. I was thinking by Java, since I'm new to C++. I forgot that anything that isn't 0 is true in C++. I understand what you mean now. Hopefully I can get this done if not I shall probably try to get some help again. Thanks so much!

Comment: Sure. No problem. Don't forget you have to `delete` all those `Element`s allocated with `new` in your `main()` or elsewhere when you're done with them.

Comment: Are u talking about the Element in the heap that is pointed to by the "ptr"? I'm not sure how exactly I would do that, since I never really allocated the space in the first place now that I think of it(?)

Comment: I've added a `main()` to the sample code in my answer. ... and fixed not allocating memory in the first place ^^

Comment: By creating "Element **elements;" , are you pretty much allocating memory or does the allocation happen in "Element **array = new Element*[num_elements];"?

Comment: `Element **elements;` is a *pointer to pointer to Element*. You need memory it points to allocated with `Element **array = new Element*[num_elements];` ... `ptr` which is a *reference to the pointer to pointer to Element* is later assigned `array`. You could use `ptr = new Element*[num_elements];` and spare the extra variable and the assignment at the end of the function.

Comment: Okie thankies! I will try my best to go through the code some more and perhaps draw some diagrams to make sure I understand it. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: You have to differ between the array of pointers (allocated with `new Element*[]`) and the single Elements the pointers in the array point to (allocated with `new Element`).

Comment: The teacher giving such assignments should be tarred and feathered. No (same) programmer would ever do such things in modern C++.

Comment: Nee ~ What do you mean by differ between them. I know that the array of pointers, each of them will point to the new Element that is part of the node. O ^ O

Comment: Yes. And these pointers in the nodes are later assigned to the `array[0]`, `array[1]`, `array[2]`, ..., `array[num_elements-1]` of the array and the nodes get `delete`d. (`delete`ing a node won't `delete` the pointer to the `Element` within the node)

Comment: Ah okie I see! Thanks ~ ^^

Comment: When I try to compile, I keep getting int table(Element **&pt) stating that pt, Element, read_table are not being declared in this scope (scope of my main).
However in my element.h file, I have the struct for Element and the prototype "int table(Element **&pt)" in it.
My main file and table.cpp has #include "element.h", so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.
edit: the scope thing also happens in the element.h file

Comment: How about you open a new question since that has nothing to do with the topic here?